# How to load the value from a nested_attribute's attached_file into an edit form so that the attachment is not deleted on update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, simple-form

I have a Paperclip attachment (a .gpx) on a Track, which `belongs_to` a Route.
My Route `accepts_nested_attributes_for :track`, and the Route `new` form receives the user's .gpx to create the Track model. This all works great for #create. However, if I go to the edit action, the form shows no file selected, and #update **will delete** the Track's attachment unless a file is reselected.

I think I need the form to reference the attached file when #edit is called, but I don't know how to do this. Help would be greatly appreciated!

The form partial looks like this:

```
= simple_form_for @route do |r|
  = r.simple_fields_for :track do |t|
    = t.input :gpx
  = r.input :title
  = r.input :description
  = r.button :submit
```

which produces this beneath the file field in the edit view

```
<input id="route_track_attributes_id" name="route[track_attributes][id]" type="hidden" value="33">
```

Inside the `RoutesController`

```
def route_params
  params.require(:route).permit(:title, :description, :distance, :total_ascent, track_attributes: [:gpx])
end
```

Comment: Can you also update your edit action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `:id` and ':_destroy' in your permit params.

```
def route_params
  params.require(:route).permit(:title, :description, :distance, :total_ascent, track_attributes: [:gpx, :id, :_destroy])
end
```

Also you are input instead of file in your form.

```
= simple_form_for @route do |r|
  = r.simple_fields_for :track do |t|
  = t.file :gpx, as: :file 
  = r.input :title
  = r.input :description
  = r.button :submit
```

Comment: Thank you! Just adding `:id` to permissible params solved the problem. Seems obvious on hindsight!

Comment: simple_fields_for's form object does not take `file`. `input` seems to work.